# STL nested vector of 2 objects

Tags: c++, vector, stl

How could I create a nested STL vector and relate two class objects? Currently I only thinking of iterating using for loop over transaction vector and compare ID's, which I assume not very efficient. Thank you. My preferred way to implement is vector and I want to store products user purchased. Products can be purchased by many users.

```
    class Products {
    public:
       int productID; // unique
       // product information variables
    };

    // User class
    class User {
    public:
        int userID;
        int productID;
// some more variables
    };

    int main() {
    // STL vector holding productID's purchased by the users.
    }
```

Comment: What does "nested" mean here? A map would probably be good here. I suggest a user has a vector of pointers to products it has ordered.

Comment: @NeilKirk Thank you for your reply. Ok then, so How would you store vector of pointers for each User? Do I need to use nested vector? I was considering this implementation approach vector<vector<User> > customers;

Comment: As a member of User, `vector<Products*>` I don't know why you want a vector of vectors.

Comment: @NeilKirk are you trying to say create 1 dimension vector as store like this: {John bread, John milk }, instead of creating 2 separate vectors, where outer vector will store object, and inner vector will store multiple products?

Comment: You have a vector of available products somewhere as a kind of database. User contains a vector of pointers to within this database. Assuming a max of 1 product per user. Otherwise you could use a map of product pointers to number purchased.

Comment: @NeilKirk I see what you mean, map may be the easier way to do, however as I am more familiar with vectors, that way I was considering it as my primary choice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your Answer if you haven't figured out yet:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
using namespace std;

class Products {
public:    
    int _productID;
    Products(int productID):_productID(productID){}
    Products(){}

    bool operator < (const Products & product) const {
        return _productID < product._productID;
    }
};

class User {
public:
    int _userID;
    int _productID;
    User(int userId, int productID): _userID(userId), _productID(productID){}
    User(){}
};

int main() {
    map<Products,User> mapVariable;
    User user(1,1);
    Products product(1);

    // for inserting into map
    mapVariable.insert(make_pair(product,user)); //type 1
    mapVariable[product] = user;  // type 2

    // for reading values in loop
    for(auto mapElem: mapVariable){
        cout << "productID: " <<mapElem.first._productID << endl;
        cout << "userId: " << mapElem.second._userID << endl;
    }
}
```

of course there are lots of ways to insert and read form map, but its for your start.